# ScoreLoop achievements not posting to Facebook or Twitter while saying that successful

Tags: android, mobile, game-engine, libgdx, scoreloop

I wanted to see if you can help me out with this.
I've got ScoreLoop running in my android game and I've got everything in order apart from one thing.
When I try to post my achievement on Facebook or Twitter the app tells me it was successfully posted, but there aren't any posts on my Facebook timeline or either on the Twitter page. Is 
there anything I could be missing?

I do have the Internet Permissions and others included. The achievements are saving correctly.

(I'm on Samsung Galaxy S2 on ICS 4.0.4 if that's of any use to you)

I am using the ScoreLoopUI and I do have the PostOverlayActivity added. The tool even logs in to Facebook and Twitter through a webview dialog.

Could it be Facebook not showing the posts, like if posting a "localhost or debugger" post?

Answer (score 0):

the FB posts are not appearing since you do not have a published distribution set for your game. Scoreloop at the moment only posts to FB when a published distribution is set for the game with Scoreloop. This is because, in the post.. there is a download link to your game from where your friends could download the game. If the game does not have a published distribution set, the link cannot be created.

If you have not yet submitted your Game to Scoreloop, please go ahead and do it so that Scoreloop can publish your distribution. If you have already submitted the game, please check the state of your distribution on developer.scoreloop.com. In case of issues, please post a msg on support.scoreloop.com and the support team will get back to you on this.